# Issue with retrieving data from Graph API to PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm starting to work with PowerShell scripts and I'm having an issue with `user.accountEnabled`. I found out that I need to use the appropriate select statement when retrieving data, so I'm using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=displayname,accountEnabled,userPrincipalName
```

I'm using the app ID and app secret, and I confirmed in Postman (using the same credentials) that I'm getting correct responses without any permission issues, and everything looks fine.

My problem is that when I assign the `accountEnabled` data to a variable, no value is added.

Below is the script with sensitive data censored.

```
function Get-ListOfExchangeUsers {
    # Dane do połączenia z bazą danych
    $ServerName = "x"
    $DatabaseName = "pwa"

    # Połączenie z bazą danych
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerName;Database=$DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True"
    $SqlConnection.Open()

    $TenantId = "x"
    # Identyfikator aplikacji
    $AppId = "x"
    # Tajny klucz aplikacji
    $AppSecret = "x"

    # Utwórz adres URL żądania tokena
    $authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

    # Utwórz obiekt żądania tokenu
    $tokenRequestBody = @{
        grant_type    = "client_credentials"
        client_id     = $AppId
        client_secret = $AppSecret
        scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
    }

    # Wyślij żądanie tokenu do usługi Azure AD
    $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $authUrl -Body $tokenRequestBody

    # Pobierz token dostępu z odpowiedzi
    $accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

    # Utwórz nagłówek autoryzacji z tokenem dostępu
    $authHeader = @{
        "Authorization" = "Bearer $accessToken"
        "Content-Type"  = "application/json"
    }

    # Wykonaj żądanie API Microsoft Graph w celu pobrania użytkowników
    $graphUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=displayname,accountEnabled,userPrincipalName"
    $Users = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $graphUrl -Headers $authHeader

    # Dodaj pobrane dane użytkowników do tabeli "allmailboxes" w bazie danych "pwa"
    foreach ($user in $Users.value) {
        $email = $user.userPrincipalName
        
        # Zapytanie SQL sprawdzające, czy istnieje już użytkownik o podanym adresie email w tabeli allmailboxes
        $query = "SELECT * FROM allmailboxes WHERE EmailAddress = '$email'"
        
        $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $SqlConnection)
        $result = $command.ExecuteScalar()
        
        # Jeśli zapytanie zwróciło wynik, to znaczy że taki użytkownik już istnieje w bazie danych - pomiń go
        if ($null -ne $result) {
            # Sprawdź, czy konto użytkownika jest wyłączone
         
            $accountEnabled = $user.accountEnabled
           
            Write-Host $email
            Write-Host $accountEnabled

            if ($accountEnabled -eq $false) {
                $query = "UPDATE allmailboxes SET Disabled = 'true' WHERE EmailAddress = '$email'"
                $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $SqlConnection)
                $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
                continue
            }
            continue
        }

        # Pobierz informację o tym, czy konto jest wyłączone czy włączone
        $disabled = $user.accountEnabled
        
        # Jeśli taki użytkownik nie istnieje w bazie danych, dodaj go do tabeli allmailboxes
        $fullName = $user.displayName
        $query = "INSERT INTO allmailboxes (FullName, EmailAddress, Disabled) VALUES ('$fullName', '$email', '$disabled')"
        $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $SqlConnection)
        $command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }

    # Zamknij połączenie z bazą danych
    $SqlConnection.Close()

    # Zwróć listę użytkowników
    return $Users
}
```

I added a line to the script to display the values of accountEnabled, and it shows a null value.

[image: Powershell]

The last account on the list is disabled and should return a different value than the others. I am also attaching the response from Graph API.

[image: API]

Could someone take a look at this and verify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it but, `$select` will be expanded into nothing if it's not been assigned. Is it declared elsewhere?

Comment: Definitely needs single quotes in the URI or a backtick to escape the `$` in `$select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address you want to call is

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=displayname,accountEnabled,userPrincipalName
```

Right now, because it is all in double-quotes and there is no `$select` variable anywhere, your url gets down to this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?=displayname,accountEnabled,userPrincipalName
```

If you declare your url in single-quotes, it should work fine, so:

```
$graphUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/?$select=displayname,accountEnabled,userPrincipalName'
```